# Shouldn't this hashtable be read only?

Tags: c#, hashtable, getter-setter

I have a class that has a getter function for a hashtable called _Parameters.

```
private Hashtable _Parameters = new Hashtable();
public Hashtable Parameters { get { return _Parameters; } }
```

_Parameters is not referenced anywhere else in code.  Now, since there is no setter function I would think that nothing outside of this class could modify what _Parameters has stored, only read it.  However that is not the case.  Another class calls this code (where template is an instance of the class mentioned above)

```
template.Parameters[key] = parameters[key];
```

This ends up modifying _Parameters.  How is this possible?  Do setter functions only apply if we are assigning vales with an '='?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You're returning a reference, which can be modified. But you can't override the reference itself.

Consider using a [`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732967.aspx) instead.

Consider reading up on [Immutable Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) as well. It should explain the subject to you.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  I could change the hashtable to a ReadOnlyDictionary, but it isn't my code.  I'm just trying to better understand it :)

Comment: @Claus: Just a clarification, you said *You're returning a reference, which can be modified. But you can't override the reference itself.*. More correctly, you're returning a reference to an object instance and you cannot from the outside change what object the internal variable references, since the outside sees a *copy* of the reference variable.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between changing the HashTable object or changing the content of the HashTable.

The lack of setter makes sure nobody can:

- set the HashTable to NULL
- change the reference of the HashTable to another HashTable.

The contents of the HashTable however can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the methods of the Hashtable, you just can't set it to a new value (such as NULL or a new Hashtable instance).

For example, if I have a List of strings and a Property with a getter but no setter, I can add to the list, remove from the list, call the Clear() method to empty out the list... but I can't do a myList = null (or myList = new List()) because there's no setter.

I'm getting the reference to the object, which allows me to manipulate it, but without a setter I cannot set the reference to a new object.

Answer (score 1):

When you return `_Parameters`, you're not returning a brand new Hashtable. You're returning another reference to the same one. This one, being a reference to the same object, has the full interface of `Hashtable` usable on it, including things which modify it. What the lack of a setter does is prevent you from replacing the previous `_Parameters` with a brand new `Hashtable`

Answer (score 1):

Having a read only property to a class object (as opposed to a struct) only prevents modifying the value of the property, in this case the object reference. However, when you access the property you get a reference to your internal HashTable object, and you are free to call any public method on the HashTable object returned, including adding and removing entries in the HashTable. What that read only property does is prevent a caller from replacing your HashTable object with a completley different HashTable object.